# How do differentiate the grid between landscape and portrait

Tags: ionic2

I'm aware of how to work with the grid in:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid/

But what I don't understand is how to structure it - for landscape vs portrait ?

I'm looking for a way to do this, but `col-[xs|sm|md]` has no affect ( only on devices it has affect - i.e: phone vs tablet )

#### Portrait

[image]

#### Landscape

[image]

Comment: What phone did you test in?

Comment: didn't think it matters, because I experience it both iPad iOS & Android Nexus 5

Comment: I ask it because `col-md` is triggered when screen-width >= 768px. It mean, when you test in Nexsus 5 for example with screen size is 412*732, `col-md` will not trigger. You will not see any affect. In that case, you should use `col-sm` instead

Answer (score 1):

You should edit you .scss and use css media queries to get what you want.

If you want to apply this for whole apps you can edit app.scss or else you can edit your-page.scss file.

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .col {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

further more, you may read this https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

**Edited**
If your columns are dynamic, it can't be done automatically, you need to add class to your ion-col, e.g.

```
<ion-col class="col-class-1">This text 1</ion-col>
<ion-col class="col-class-2">This text 2</ion-col>
```

and edit your scss

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .col.col-class-1 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  .col.col-class-2 {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: but the columns are not always 50% ( `col-xs-[2|4|etc..]` ) how do I keep it dynamic ? it's also not always `%`, it sometimes fixed right ( in `px` for non-responsive ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">.col</div>
    <div class="col">.col</div>        
</div>
```

Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#grid-responsive

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

Regular grid of Ionic 2 does covert this, but the thing was that `iPhone 5` for example has:

- Landscape, W: 568px, H: 320px
- Portrait , W: 320px, H: 568px

But the Ionic 2 defaults is:

```
xs  0
sm  576px    <= Landscape width (568px) still less than that
```

So I've edited the file:
`variables.scss`

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 420px,     <= Lowered the value
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);
```

Which made the columns in the grid to work out of the box

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 col-sm-6 *ngFor="let card of cards">
          Card X
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

- Portrait: will show a single card in a "row" (stacked cards, col-12 )
- Landscape: will show two cards in a "row" (12/col-6 = 2 columns in a row)